# Arrow length in function align

Tags: arrows

How can I change the length of the arrows in the below code ?

```
 \documentclass{report}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{float}


\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}


\setlength{\textwidth}{6.2in} \setlength{\textheight}{9.0in}
\hoffset=-0.8truein \voffset=-0.6truein




 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}


 \usepackage{tikz-cd}

 \usepackage[arrow]{xy}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  r \colon \text{\textlatin{Spec}}R &\to R/P \\
  P &\mapsto r\mod{P}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you expand your code to a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) starting with a `\documentclass` ending with `\end{document}`?

Comment: @AlainRemillard I am not sure what you mean, in the main.tex it states \documentclass{report}

Comment: @burbaki they mean could you edit that into the code in your question. People cannot guess what `\usepackage`'s, `documentclass` and custom commands you have used, it helps people help you if you make the code compile so we can copy and paste it and test it straight away

Comment: Please provide a small but complete document, which we can compile aa it is and which, of course, replicate your problem,

Comment: Also, I think it would be helpful to clarify what you want to achieve. Do you just want slightly longer arrows? Or slightly shorter? Or do you want to be able to choose an exact length? Or something else?

Comment: I just added \longrightarrow and  \longmapsto and it works fine

Comment: I see no possible meaning in the function you're trying to define.

Comment: For future reference, your code is a Working Example. To make it Minimal, remove the package that are not needed (e.g. float, cancel). We want to have the smallest code to work with.

Comment: Off topic: `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, so it's not necessary to load `amsfonts` separately.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but `amsmath` provides `\longrightarrow` and `\longmapsto` for longer arrows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  r \colon \Spec R &\longrightarrow R/P \\
  P &\longmapsto r\mod{P}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Also, it is unrelated to your question but it is generally a bad idea to write math operators with `\text` (for example, if you write `\text{Spec}` in a theorem written in italic, then "Spec" will also be written in italic). It is better to define a command for the operator, for example with `\DeclareMathOperator`.